# Does Elixir provide an easier way to get a GenServer process's current state?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

Given a simple `GenServer` process.

```
defmodule KVServer do
  use GenServer

  def start do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, %{}, name: :kv_server)
  end

  def store(k, v) do
    GenServer.cast(:kv_server, {:store, k, v})
  end

  def handle_cast({:store, k, v}, state) do
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, k, v)}
  end
end
```

I can get the current process state using `:sys.get_status/1`

```
iex(1)> {:ok, pid} = KVServer.start
{:ok, #PID<0.119.0>}
iex(2)> KVServer.store(:a, 1)
:ok
iex(3)> KVServer.store(:b, 2)
:ok
iex(4)> {_,_,_,[_,_,_,_,[_,_,{_,[{_,state}]}]]} = :sys.get_status(pid)
...
iex(5)> state
%{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Just wondering is there an easier way provided by Elixir to get a `GenServer` process's current state?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`:sys.get_state/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#get_state-1):

```
iex(1)> {:ok, pid} = KVServer.start
{:ok, #PID<0.86.0>}
iex(2)> KVServer.store(:a, 1)
:ok
iex(3)> KVServer.store(:b, 2)
:ok
iex(4)> :sys.get_state(pid)
%{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: Thank you! How I missed that in the documentation!